# Angular 6 routing

Tags: angular

I want to do a simple routing for error 404.
If a link is corrupt, I want to redirect the user to page 404.
My login page works fine, but I do not see where I'm wrong with the error page.
This is my file [structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJeOk.png). And this is [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXYvz.png) i get when try to load page.
I you have some idea thi would be great!

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import 'hammerjs';

import { FuseModule } from '@fuse/fuse.module';
import { FuseSharedModule } from '@fuse/shared.module';

import { fuseConfig } from './fuse-config';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FuseMainModule } from './main/main.module';
import { FuseSampleModule } from './main/content/sample/sample.module';
import { Login2Module } from './main/content/login-2/login-2.module';
import { Error404Module } from './main/content/errors/404/error404.module';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '/errors/404/error404',
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    TranslateModule.forRoot(),

    // Fuse Main and Shared modules
    FuseModule.forRoot(fuseConfig),
    FuseSharedModule,
    FuseMainModule,
    FuseSampleModule,
    Login2Module,
    Error404Module
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**error.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material';

import { FuseSharedModule } from '@fuse/shared.module';

import { FuseError404Component } from './error404.component';

const routes = [
  {
    path: 'error404',
    component: FuseError404Component
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    FuseError404Component
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),

    MatIconModule,

    FuseSharedModule
  ]
})
export class Error404Module {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are redirecting to '/errors/404/error404', but there's no such route.

You should either add a 404-component or redirect to an existing path.

**Update** based on your comment:

```
{
    path: '**',
    component: FuseError404Component,
}
```

Comment: I add FuseError404Component in my error404.module.ts

Comment: @NemanjaAndric you need to add routing entrty for the same in `app.module.ts` too, like I added in my answer above

Comment: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'errors/404/error404'

Comment: @NemanjaAndric well, there is no such a route. Your route has the url segment 'error404'. Overall, your code is pretty confusing, the longer I look into it. Why do you have two 404 components?

Answer (score 0):

IMO you haven't declared any route using path `/errors/404/error404`

You need to add routing configuration for the same like this -

```
{
        path: '/errors/404/error404',
        loadChildren: 'app/not-found-component/not-found-component.module#NotFoundComponentModule'
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

just change `RouterModule.forChild(routes)` to `RouterModule.forRoot(routes)`.